# MySQL metadata for table rows

Tags: mysql, metadata

I have a question about how to save metadata for table rows.

For example, I have a table which contains data about images `items_images`.
id, INT(20)
title, VARCHAR(255)
date_added, DATETIME
...

Now I want to add a voting system where users can vote "like" or "dislike" for the image items. Should I just add two new fields to the `items_images`:
votes_like, INT(20)
votes_dislike, INT(20)

or should I create a separate table to store this meta data `votes`:
item_id, INT(20)
votes_like, INT(20)
votes_dislike, INT(20)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Don't repeat the data ! You are supposed to store who voted, right? You should create a new table like your later approach.

See:

[Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood it, you just want to save, the number of likes and dislikes and not who voted. Than I would alter the table and and the two columns, because it is slightly faster than a second table.

If you want to save the votes, I mean who voted, I totally aggree with [Sarfraz Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139459/sarfraz-ahmed)